# Expanding a factorial summation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I was working with a counting problem and derived a formula that sufficed for the entire solution.
Upon looking closer, I noticed that this formula was always summing to 
$$ n!/2 $$

My answer is acceptable as I have it, but the formula I derived is as follows. I am curious to see if there is a way of expanding this summation to get $n!/2$ rather than an open summation.

$$\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} (n-x)((n-2)!)$$

Comment: Do you mean $(n-2)!\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} (n-x)$ or $\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} [(n-x)(n-2)]!$

Comment: The first, the factorial only applies to the (n-2) term! Will edit and revise

Comment: Are you looking for a proof that the sum is equal to $\frac{n!}{2}$?

Comment: yes, I attempted to rearrange the equation but wasn't getting very far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is equal to 
$$
(n-2)! \sum_{x=1}^n (n-x)
$$
Let's look at that sum...
$$
\sum_1^n (n-x) = (n-1) + (n-2) + \ldots + 2 + 1 + 0
$$
which is just the sum of the first $n-1$ postive integers, which is 
$$
\frac{(n-1)\cdot n}{2}
$$
So your overall expression is
$$
(n-2)! \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2} = \frac{n!}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)(n-2)!=(n-2)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)$$

Now notice that by symmetry,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)=\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}2}_{\text{Triangle numbers}}$$

Thus, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(n-k)(n-2)!=(n-2)!\frac{n(n-1)}2=\frac{n!}2$$

as claimed.

---

[Wikipedia: Triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)